# How to apply following formula for visible cells only?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell, visible

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,A2:J6)&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

The above formula is for combining multi columns in one column.

I need to apply above formula for visible cells only.
"d" is filtered in "A" column but still present in the results.

Please help me.

Thank you.

[image: Before Filtering]

[image: After Filtering]

[MyFile](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oUxtCyvX32gd5XjqMvwTP4di-g64nSv5/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=111310305301919035723&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: What is the condition you use for filtering? Wouldn't you want the formula to do that for you instead? Also instead of FILTERXML I think you could use =SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(O2:X10,1)))` you could expand this by adding a filter in the formula.

Comment: Optionally, the filter is used on one of the columns from O to X, and as a result, the number of rows is reduced.

Comment: Yes, but if you can explain what's being filtered, you/we may be able to apply that by formula. This is a question with zero context, but I think the context matters. Please post some sample data and example(s) of what you want and why.

Comment: very thanks, I uploaded my file, also I use Microsoft Office 2021.

Comment: why wouldn't `=SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(FILTER(A2:J6,A2:A6<>"d"),1)))` be an answer? (By the way, the file is not accessible without requesting access)

Comment: I have Microsoft office 2021 and it does not have this function (TOCOL).

Comment: `=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,FILTER(A2:J6,A2:A6<>"d"))&"</s></t>","//s")))`

Comment: thank you; 
I don't want to enter the filter in the formula but I want the calculation to be applied to the visible cells when I do the filter.

Comment: So i was in the right way, OP is looking for filtered data i.e. visible data only

Comment: It is exactly like that. I am waiting for your answer. Thanks

Comment: Unless you have an end goal with the values present after filtering (summing, average, or anything) I think VBA is the only way to get there. If you want to do something to the values you could look into SUBTOTAL()

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that may help you if the dataset isn't too large:

This solution requires a helper column.

If we put `=ROW()^10` in `K2` and drag that down to the end of your range (or use `=ROW(A2:J6)^10` at once) then we created a helper column of values that if we sum combinations they will always sum up to unique values. We will use that in our solution.

As we manually filter out any of the rows, the lines of the helper column would get filtered out as well. The function `SUBTOTAL` has the built in function to work with unfiltered data only. In this case we use SUM and the argument for that is `109`. We can make use of that in our solution:

```
=LET(range,   A2:J6,
     helper,  K2:K6,
     r,       ROWS(range),
     visible, REDUCE("",BASE(SEQUENCE(SUM(COMBIN(r,SEQUENCE(r)))),2,r),
              LAMBDA(x,y,
              IF( SUM(FILTER(helper,--MID(y,SEQUENCE(r),1)))=SUBTOTAL(109,helper),
                  FILTER(range,--MID(y,SEQUENCE(r),1)),x))),
SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(visible,1))))
```

*before manual filter*
[image]

*after applying manual filter*
[image]
Basically the formula checks if the sum for all possible combinations of the helper column equals the filtered subtotal of the helper column than apply a filter to the combination of these rows.

I know REDUCE or LAMBDA don't work in Office 2021, so I changed the FILTERXML to TOCOL in this formula.

While it will not work in Office 2021 I think you do have access to excel for the web and all this will work there. I hope that helps you in your situation.

---

**EDIT Excel 2021 solution:**

Alternate solution which I think uses solely functions compatible with Excel 2021:

```
=LET(range,   Sheet1!A2:J6,
     helper,  Sheet1!K2:K6,
     r,       ROWS(range),
     combin,  SUBSTITUTE(MID(BASE(SEQUENCE(SUM(COMBIN(r,SEQUENCE(r)))),2,r),SEQUENCE(,r),1)*SEQUENCE(,r),0,""),
     rowcomb, --IF(MMULT(IFERROR(INDEX(helper,combin,0),0),SEQUENCE(r,,,0))=SUBTOTAL(109,helper),combin,""),
     res,     TRANSPOSE(FILTER(rowcomb,ISNUMBER(INDEX(rowcomb,,1)))),
     resrows, INDEX(range,FILTER(res,ISNUMBER(res)),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(range))),
SORT(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",1,resrows)&"</s></t>","//s"))))
```

Comment: I have MS Office Excel 2021. Therefore, it will be difficult for me to use the online version. thank you

Comment: *Microsoft 365 for the web is a free version of Microsoft 365 that you can use in a web browser. All you need is to sign up for a Microsoft account with a new or existing email address.  Use Word, Excel, PowerPoint and more for free on the web.* source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-s-the-difference-between-microsoft-365-and-office-2021-ed447ebf-6060-46f9-9e90-a239bd27eb96 Have you tried it? office.com

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhxknrNHLDPC_FlNQylgXP84rpjc?e=Dn8laE

Comment: As an alternative you may copy the filtered columns A:J in your data sheet and paste it in the next sheet and filter on that:
`=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",1,DROP(A:J,1))&"</s></t>","//s")))`. Else you really need to tag vba.

Comment: I posted an alternative which I think works with compatible functions.

Comment: =LET(range,   Sheet1!A2:J6,
     helper,  Sheet1!K2:K6,
     r,       ROWS(range),
     combin,  SUBSTITUTE(MID(BASE(SEQUENCE(SUM(COMBIN(r,SEQUENCE(r)))),2,r),SEQUENCE(,r),1)*SEQUENCE(,r),0,""),
     rowcomb, --IF(MMULT(IFERROR(INDEX(helper,combin,0),0),SEQUENCE(r,,,0))=SUBTOTAL(109,helper),combin,""),
     res,     TRANSPOSE(FILTER(rowcomb,ISNUMBER(INDEX(rowcomb,,1)))),
     resrows, INDEX(range,FILTER(res,ISNUMBER(res)),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(range))),
SORT(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",1,resrows)&"</s></t>","//s"))))

above Formula return !VALUE# error.

Comment: Is the sheet name correct? Else, please post a screenshot