# Vlookup only visible cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel workbook structured the following way:
Change sheet
Main data sheet (filterable by date)
Main data control sheet (filterable by date)

Data is regularly entered in a warehouse, and the data sheets are pullet from there, so there is a lot of repeating data. What I want to achieve regularly is checking if there are any changes between the main and control sheets one filtered to a specific date, the other is filtered to another date, and then pull the relevant entry from the main sheet to the change sheet (so only working with visible cells is a must).

On the Change sheet, there is a table:
In column A, a macro copies the text from column A of the main data sheet, and the table is resized to only extend until the last row with data in it.

| Copied values from Main data | Department | Country |  Address | etc

In each column there is a different data I want to be able to see if it changed, and there are currently 8 columns, with the possibility of more later on. At once there are ~300-350 lines filtered, but the source data on the main sheet is in the 1000s and growing.

I have this array formula and it works:
IF(VLOOKUP(A2,'Main data'!A:C,3,FALSE)=VLOOKUP(A2,'Main data control'!A:C,3,FALSE),"",VLOOKUP(A2,'Main data'!A:C,3,FALSE))

However, I noticed a considerable decrease in performance even with only 3 columns having this formula, and I'm afraid it will break Excel if I complete the table with this.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to set the last rows value in the references for columns A:C

Comment: I would start off with either advising to use VBA if possible, if you plan to actually filter on visible cells, else use helper cells to set your filter criteria you can also use to compare both sets with these conditions. If both are not an option look into this https://stackoverflow.com/a/77006782/12634230 it uses a workaround to filter on visible cells, but (again) it's not recommended to follow that path, since it's likely too heavy for your datasets.

Comment: I would also go with vba, but I'm a bit new to that, so I'm unsure how to start. Can you give an example of how that would look like? The workaround seems like it would lead to the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since visualising your context adequately is challenging, the suggestion proposed below is illustrated using the most simple of tables:
[image: Screenshot illustrating suggested solution when no filter is active]
(un-filtered table)

[image: Screenshot illustrating suggested solution when later filter is active]
(data filtered for later date)

[image: Screenshot illustrating suggested solution when later filter is active]
(data filtered for earlier date)

The formula in `B10` is

```
=INDEX(C2:C7,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(B1,ROW(A1:A6)*(A2:A7=A10),))*ROW(A1:A6),1))
```

which I imagine you will have to enter as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) since 'visible cells' suggests you are using Excel 2019 or earlier.

Cells referenced:

- `C2:C7` range from which result will be returned
- `B1` header cell for range being filtered
- `A1:A6` because there are 6 rows of *data* in the sample table
- `A2:A7` range against which lookup value is to be matched

As it is a [volatile function](https://exceljet.net/glossary/volatile-function), the use of `OFFSET()` is frowned upon but, on the assumption of your using legacy Excel, it is required here - it should be employed in *as few cells of your file as possible*, because its persistent recalculation will otherwise negatively impact the performance of all open workbooks.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply! The dataset is quite large, thousands of lines, and they /will/ be going into the tens of thousands eventually. Filtered it's only 300ish currently, but that's still a lot a lines to go over. In the destination table, there would be 6-8 variations so alltogether it's 300x8 formulas. So in this case wouldn't this result in the same issue of degraded performance as my original formula?

Comment: @sequelnoob, I posted sample data because I couldn't visualise your context, and I _still_ can't: there's a world of difference between a formula having to 'scan' 300 rows out of thousands, vs having 2,400 copies of the formula.... As for your original formula, you would benefit from using a helper column since `VLOOKUP(A2,'Main data'!A:C,3,FALSE)` is calculated **twice** in each formula (referring to a helper cell containing just that part of the formula would mean it was calculated only once (per instance of the larger formula))